# How do I prevent passport plugin from going in forever loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js

Signup is handled using passport plugin. And it goes in forever loop when user signs up. When I was debugging, I paused execution and the pointer was found to be inside emitHookFactory function inside async_hooks.js file which is core node module. I resumed execution and paused may times but pointer happened to be there.

The call stack showed this
emitDestroyNative (async_hooks.js:168)

Since in forever loop, the output is nothing but browser sends request again after few seconds to same script.

I have been debugging a lot but found no solution in fixing it.

How do I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Edit: code added

```
passport.authenticate('local-signup', function (err, user, info) {
                    let isJSON = false
                    if (req.body.json) isJSON = true
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("passport.authenticate err ==", err);
                        if (isJSON) return res.json({ status: false })
                        return res.redirect("back");
                    }
                    if (!user) {
                        if (isJSON) return res.json({ status: false })
                        return res.redirect("back");
                    }
                    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("req.logIn err ==", err);
                            if (isJSON) return res.json({ status: false })
                            req.flash(
                                "error",
                                "Something Went Wrong: Please try again later."
                            );
                            if (isJSON) return res.json({ status: false })
                            return res.redirect("back");
                        }
})
```

Comment: Some code please?

Comment: @Still_learning code added

Comment: There are two if(isJSON) statements inside the req.logIn block. Is that intentional, or is one supposed to be if(!isJSON) ? Because it looks like the second one will never be accessed, since you're 'returning' out of the if statement in the first one.

Comment: Good point @Still_learning - also is it just me or doesn't the `req.logIn` block have any closing brackets , does it ? Looks like it's missing a `})` after the `if (err) { }` statement